# Schedule a push notification with Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm integrating push notifications in an app I'm developing. I have chosen to use Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to support both Android and iOS.

When using the console to send a push message I see there is an option to delay the actual sending of the push notification. However when checking the [HTTP docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) I can't seem to find this option.

How would I schedule a notification so it is send at a later time using FCM and the HTTP API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of the moment, there is no API or even a parameter that you can use in order to schedule a notification.

It can only be done either (as you already know) in the Firebase Console or implementing a delay until the schedule in your own App Server.