# android firebase schedule notification programmatically (even in months)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification

I am developing a personal app on android studio with java and firebase, in this specific project I don't have registration, protection or something else, just the java code connected to the firebase realtime database.
I'm trying to handle notifications for the first time, I have elements with a release date, I need to trigger a notification when the day of this date comes, it could be days, months or years from the date of creation.
There is a way to do it on firebase? like create programmatically a notification with a specific date scheduled, or, setting some firebase backend code, etc..?
I looked at the other similar questions but found nothing that could guide me in solving my specific problem.
what is the best way to archieve this?
If it's not possible with firebase, what are the other options?

The question that comes closest it's this:
[How to trigger notification from firebase at a specific time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814403/how-to-trigger-notification-from-firebase-at-a-specific-time)

From what I understand what I need can't be done (the question was from 2017 now I don't know if anything has changed), the only way to do it is to set up a server, but it doesn't explain how

Comment: Nothing significantly changed about the abilities in Firebase Cloud Messaging around delivering messages on a schedule. You can: 1) schedule a local notification on the device through Android's APIs, 2) schedule a message in the Firebase console, 3) send a message by calling the API, but you will have to schedule that API call yourself then.

Comment: ok I have to create another question to know the best way to do it without firebase? 
like the best pratice in this case to apply, the best technology to use, etc..?
because I find only question where the app is an alarm that need to send notification every x hours, I don't need this, I need to schedule a different notification time for each element, and this time can be a day, a month and even a year, I'm really lost I can't find a way to do it

Comment: That sounds like opinionated or asking for a recommendation, both of which are off-topic on Stack Overflow. You can use whatever technology you're comfortable with that allows you to meet your requirement. And don't rule out option #1 I mentioned above, as it's by far the easiest - and unfortunately also the most underutilized.

Comment: I'll give a look to the first option then, found WorkManager API, gonna try it, thanks for you time